# Can't unpin files from taskbar in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar

I have a few files pinned to SumatraPDF on my taskbar and I can't unpin two of them. They seem to be stuck. I've tried removing Sumatra from my taskbar and re-adding it, but all my pins persisted. I tried opening them, but they didn't exist. Then a popup appeared asking if I wanted to remove the dead links, so I clicked yes, but they're still there.

Does anyone know how I can get rid of them?

Comment: Does it still happen after killing DWM? In CMD: `taskkill /im dwm.exe`

Comment: I'm just getting `ERROR: The process "dwm.exe" with PID 500 could not be terminated. Reason: Access is denied.` I ran it from an admin command prompt.

Comment: try to clean registry using ccleaner.

Comment: I just tried that. Unfortunately they're still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why this is happening, but I found a solution to the problem.

There are two folders where the jump lists are stored:

- `C:\Users\Asher\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations`
- `C:\Users\Asher\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations`

The files aren't named according the application, so you'll have to look through them manually. Once you find the corresponding file, just delete it. You'll have to readd your previous jump files, but at least the stuck ones will be gone.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me

Comment: @reggaeguitar, sorry to hear that. This issue keeps coming up for me, so I've stopped trying to fix it. I hope you figure something out!

Comment: Thanks, it's only one icon (Starcraft 2) so not that big of a deal, have a good day!